# Consolidating multiple UPDATE queries

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to consolidate multiple UPDATE queries to a single query in PostgreSQL.

Here is the schema for the table in question: pointDailyHistory

```
 id         | integer | not null default nextval('pointdailyhistory_id_seq'::regclass)
 deposit    | integer | not null default 0
 withdrawal | integer | not null default 0
 balance    | integer | not null default 0
 depositday | date    | not null
Indexes:
    "pointdailyhistory_depositday_key" UNIQUE, btree (depositday)
```

The purpose of this table is to keep track of points gained (deposits) and points consumed (withdrawal) on a daily basis. The reason for doing so is to enable a policy where points gained first are first to be consumed (FIFO, in a sense)

Suppose I gained 100 points on Dec 1st. I would then perform the following INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO pointDailyHistory (deposit, balance, depositday) VALUES (100,100,'2016-12-01');
```

Suppose I gained another 50 points on the same day. I would then perform the following UPDATE:

```
UPDATE pointDailyHistory SET deposit=deposit+50,balance=balance+50 WHERE depositday='2016-12-01';
```

If I gain 30 points on the next day (Dec 2nd), I would perform the following INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO pointDailyHistory (deposit, balance, depositday) VALUES (30,30,'2016-12-02');
```

Easy so far. Now, for withdrawals. In order to satisfy the FIFO mentioned above,
I want to perform a withdrawal on the oldest day whose balance is greater than zero.

So if I were to withdraw 160 points on Dec 3rd, I'd perform the following:

```
UPDATE pointdailyhistory SET withdrawal=150,balance=0 WHERE depositday='2016-12-01';
UPDATE pointdailyhistory SET withdrawal=10,balance=20 WHERE depositday='2016-12-02';
```

This is fine when updating a small number of rows but the number of UPDATE statements will skyrocket if points are gained over a wide spread of dates and consumed on a single day.

Any hints, solutions will be most welcome!

Comment: I wouldn't store the balance in the first place and I wouldn't `update` existing rows for the same day - only insert new rows. If you need quick access to a the balance, create a second table that only holds the balance and is updated through a trigger on the pointdailyhistory table

Comment: Hello, thanks for the swift reply. I understand your second point - and although not mentioned above, I have a balance table that keeps track of the latest balance for quick reference.

As for INSERTing rather than UPDATING - I will give it a thought and see if it satisfies my requirements. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: If you already _have_ a  balance table then why keep it in the `pointdailyhistory` at all?

Comment: Hi there, the reason for this is so that I can display the balance by expiry date. Say point expire 90 days after it has been given. 
In such a case, I would use the following query:

SELECT "Points that expire on"||depositday+'90 days'::interval||" are as follows: ",balance FROM pointdailyhistory WHERE balance>0;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done as a single SQL by using a recursive CTE.

```
with recursive 
  required(amount) as (values (160)),
  chunk (depositday, balance, depth, removed, remaining) 
  as
  (
   select 
     depositday,balance,1,least(x.balance,amount), amount - least(x.balance,amount) 
   from pointdailyhistory x, required
     where x.balance > 0 and 
       not exists 
         (select * from pointdailyhistory x2 
           where x2.balance > 0 and 
                 x2.depositday < x.depositday)
   union all
   select x.depositday,x.balance,chunk.depth + 1, 
     least(x.balance, chunk.remaining),
     chunk.remaining - least(x.balance, chunk.remaining)
   from pointdailyhistory x
     inner join chunk on
       chunk.depositday < x.depositday and chunk.remaining > 0
     where 
       x.balance > 0 and
       not exists (select * from pointdailyhistory x2 
            where x2.balance > 0 and x2.depositday < x.depositday
                  and x2.depositday > chunk.depositday)
  )
update pointdailyhistory
 set withdrawal = pointdailyhistory.withdrawal + chunk.removed,
     balance =    pointdailyhistory.balance    - chunk.removed
from chunk
where pointdailyhistory.depositday = chunk.depositday;
```

The chunk CTE picks up the first pointdailyrecord entry that is to be updated by finding the oldest entry that has an outstanding balance.  It then works out how much it can remove that entry.   It then passes this information to the next iteration through the CTE (2nd half of union). The second half finds the next record which is later than the record just selected and which also has a balance.  It repeats finding all the rows that it needs to update until the amount left to withdraw has been fully allocated to various records.

This builds up a chunk CTE rowset that has

```
depositday balance depth removed remaining
2016-12-01   150     1      150      10
2016-12-02   30      2       10       0
```

Finally it uses that CTE rowset to drive the update matching on the depositday field.

I haven't done any form of performance analysis.  I expect the query plan would be interesting, so you'll want to test it yourself.

CTE documentation at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for the brilliant answer. This is what I was looking for. Will do performance testing prior to using it live!